# Query by relationship for GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

How would you use graphQL to query by a "relational" entity value?
For instance, lets say we have a bunch of person-objects. Each "person" then has a relation to an interest/hobby which then has a property called "name".
Now lets say that we want to query for the name of each person with a specific interest, how would such a query be "conducted" using GraphQL?
Using OData it would be something like Persons?$select=name&$expand(Interests($filter=name eq 'Surfing')).. what would be the equivalent for GraphQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *one* equivalent. With the exception of introspection, the GraphQL specification does not dictate what types a schema should have, what fields it should expose or what arguments those fields should take. In other words, there is no *one way* to query relationships or do things like filtering, sorting or pagination. If you use Relay, it has [its own spec](https://relay.dev/docs/en/graphql-server-specification.html) with a bit more guidance around things like pagination and connections between different nodes, but even Relay is agnostic to filtering. It's up to the individual service to decide how to implement these features.

As an example, if we set up a [Graphcool](https://www.graph.cool/docs/) or [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/docs/) server, our query might look something like this:

```
query {
  persons(where: {
    interest: {
      name: "Surfing"
    }
  }) {
    name
  }
}
```

A query to a [Hasura](https://docs.hasura.io) server might look like this:

```
query {
  persons(where: {
    interest: {
      name: {
        _eq: "Surfing"
      }
    }
  }) {
    name
  }
}
```

But there's nothing stopping you from creating a schema that would support a query like:

```
query {
  persons(interest: "Surfing") {
    name
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the answer :). So basically GraphQL deosnt follow a strict standard for how things should be done.. but its up to the devs of the service to provide a good documentation of how to use the service? Compared to for instance OData that uses a more "strict" format

Comment: I would say OData is more *opinionated* about certain things, but essentially yes. GraphQL has introspection, so it's self-documenting and there's tools like GraphiQL and GraphQL Playground that most servers use that utilize this feature to generate documentation for a server schema.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks again :)